余 with a double meaning? What is the joke here?

I came upon this cover and I don't quite understand what the joke is here. What does it mean? I mean, I get that on the right she says "If I don't go out (or let "them" out) it ends up like this" and on the left the chibi says "Let me out" or even "more out?" because the wordplay here is with 余 having a double meaning, or am I wrong? Like 余 for an archaic "me" which this character also uses throughout the manga and 余 for "more"? Could someone maybe explain the joke here or help me with a better understanding of this short scene? Thanks so much!

Why do you expect a joke here? Is this work in a comedy genre? (What work is this from, for that matter?)

@YusukeMatsubara 背表紙がちらっと見えてますが、これですね

This 余 is archaic "I/me", and it's just her first-person pronoun. There's no pun or wordplay involved. (While 余 can mean "remainder" in highly stiff and old legal documents, this is irrelevant in this context.)
I think you simply failed to catch the meaning of the verb 出す in this context. Since these pictures are on the cover, this 出せ seems to mean "(漫画の中に)出せ" or "Put me / Let me appear in the manga (not just on the cover)". Perhaps these characters weren't featured in this volume.

余を出せ!
Feature me (in the main part of the manga)!


Thanks so much! I totally missed that, yes. But in this context it makes so much sense now, because the character is not showing up in this volume. Oh man, thanks for your help!
